# Текст внутри SVG path

Tags: html, svg, svg-path

Как добавить текст внутри каждого path части? Не title, а именно текст - название данной области (svg-карта)

```
<svg
   xmlns:mapsvg="http://mapsvg.com"
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.1"
   width="792.57129"
   height="802.40002"
   mapsvg:geoViewBox="43.454090 41.303028 46.630286 38.832890" 
>
  <path
     d="m 184.5425,178.23394 3.08,-1.26 3.54,0.39 4.13,2.32 7.08,8.54 10.33,0 1.47,-7.37 5.02,-0.78 4.43,0 11.5,6.98 2.36,-2.32 2.66,0 3.84,2.71 2.36,3.88 0.29,7.76 -0.55,3.61 0,0 -0.33,2.2 6.49,8.14 2.06,5.42 8.85,10.46 7.38,2.32 14.16,2.32 -0.59,6.2 -2.06,7.73 -3.84,6.96 -4.13,5.42 -3.54,0 0.88,11.21 -4.71,10.04 0,11.58 -1.48,5.02 -7.97,-0.38 -2.36,6.17 -14.16,15.81 -3.84,2.7 -0.88,2.7 1.47,2.7 3.25,0 3.54,-1.93 3.54,0 1.77,3.08 0.59,3.86 -2.65,7.7 -1.66,2.47 0,0 -5.13,8.7 0,4.71 0,0 -4.16,-0.65 -4.47,-2.78 -19.84,-7.51 -5.75,-7.24 -1.5,-0.84 -1.49,0.56 -7.25,8.63 -3.2,1.67 -2.98,0 -3.84,-1.67 -1.92,-3.9 -2.13,-1.39 -2.35,0.83 1.28,20.04 -2.99,2.22 -22.39,-0.55 -7.46,-2.23 -15.78,-2.78 -10.45,-3.34 -9.81,-0.83 -10.88,-8.91 -3.199995,-0.83 -0.64,-4.73 -2.77,-0.84 -6.61,0 -4.69,-0.83 -7.68,-3.62 -14.29,1.11 -5.54,3.34 -1.4,1.69 0,0 -8.02,-3.59 -0.33,-5.11 -1.65,-5.47 -10.58,-10.81 -0.95,-1.86 0.83,-3.42 7.97,-13.31 -0.54,-6.12 -1.54,-3.52 -1.03,-1.65 -2.89,-2.11 0,0 4.68,-0.51 9.86,-2.58 8.22,-6.89 2.31,-4.31 6.25,-4.3 9.53,-0.87 3.29,-0.86 3.29,-2.15 2.63,-0.43 3.62,2.58 5.59,1.73 5.589995,-0.44 2.3,-1.72 2.96,0 4.28,1.72 3.94,3.02 6.91,0 7.56,-4.31 4.28,0 4.6,1.29 5.92,6.04 4.6,0.43 2.63,-1.73 2.96,-0.86 5.27,0 3.61,1.29 4.61,0 10.19,-3.87 3.62,-3.45 2.96,0 1.32,-3.45 0,-3.44 -5.6,-6.47 -0.32,-3.88 0,-5.61 2.96,-7.76 -11.84,-1.72 0,-6.91 -0.99,-3.02 -7.56,-11.66 -0.33,-4.75 0.98,-4.75 3.29,-3.89 4.94,-3.89 5.26,-1.3 7.56,-0.43 z"
     title="Aragac̣otn"
     id="AM-AG" />
  <path
     d="m 233.3325,425.38394 -1.43,-2.65 -2.73,-2.78 -6.58,-1.84 -3.04,-1.96 0,0 1.99,-15.36 -0.21,-3.33 -5.97,-7.78 -0.64,-3.61 0.85,-3.33 2.34,-1.39 5.76,-0.56 10.88,0.28 5.54,0.83 2.14,1.95 2.13,0.55 0.39,-0.81 0,0 6.6,6.55 3.84,1.54 5.01,0.38 3.84,1.92 4.72,4.99 1.77,0.77 1.48,-0.77 5.01,-5.76 5.02,-0.38 2.65,-1.15 4.72,-4.62 5.91,-3.84 5.16,-8.27 0,0 -0.59,13.84 3.24,5 6.5,1.92 5.01,-0.38 2.07,-0.77 0,-3.85 1.47,-1.53 3.54,0 2.66,-3.08 2.65,-0.77 3.54,0.39 1.19,-3.85 2.06,-3.07 17.56,-0.96 4.13,-9.23 4.42,-1.93 4.72,0.39 5.32,-2.31 23.89,0.77 1.14,-0.89 0,0 1.37,0.7 0,1.92 -3.54,19.23 0,9.99 20.95,31.86 -0.29,14.96 1.47,4.22 0,6.89 -1.47,12.65 1.98,3.54 0,0 0.38,0.67 -7.97,5.36 -3.25,5.35 -1.47,4.6 -0.79,7.14 0,0 -1.91,0 -6.17,4.31 -2.85,3.69 -2.17,5.84 -5.67,3.53 -5.72,2.31 -3.77,0.9 -14.59,0.26 -14.91,1.63 -8.52,1.16 -7.06,2.23 -2.46,-0.34 -1.26,-1.33 0.42,-4.97 -2.37,-1.38 -3.44,0.15 -1.31,-5.07 -3.3,-4.51 -1.42,-0.9 -2.8,0.94 0.16,-2.6 1.55,-4 -2.32,-1.81 -1.7,0.05 -1.95,1.59 -2.08,0.24 -13.39,-8.94 1.32,-2.37 -0.34,-1.8 -4.38,1.52 -1.59,-0.61 -0.75,-1.08 -0.41,-7 -1.68,-2.99 -4.12,-2.91 -2.36,-2.81 -1.66,-8.55 -4.24,-4.85 -4.37,-2.48 -8.56,-12.52 -5.76,-1.67 -2.58,-2.89 -8.99,-6.77 -5.47,0 z"
     title="Ararat"
     id="AM-AR" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В svg всё располагается абсолютно - то есть тег [text](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text) пишем какой надо и располагаем по нужным координатам то есть по `x` и `y` и для того что бы path не перекрывал text то сам текст располагают по иерархии ниже нужного path

> Я вычистил не нужные теги и оставил только важные типа geoviewBox
> width heigth

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="792.57129" height="802.40002" mapsvg:geoViewBox="43.454090 41.303028 46.630286 38.832890">
  <path d="m 184.5425,178.23394 3.08,-1.26 3.54,0.39 4.13,2.32 7.08,8.54 10.33,0 1.47,-7.37 5.02,-0.78 4.43,0 11.5,6.98 2.36,-2.32 2.66,0 3.84,2.71 2.36,3.88 0.29,7.76 -0.55,3.61 0,0 -0.33,2.2 6.49,8.14 2.06,5.42 8.85,10.46 7.38,2.32 14.16,2.32 -0.59,6.2 -2.06,7.73 -3.84,6.96 -4.13,5.42 -3.54,0 0.88,11.21 -4.71,10.04 0,11.58 -1.48,5.02 -7.97,-0.38 -2.36,6.17 -14.16,15.81 -3.84,2.7 -0.88,2.7 1.47,2.7 3.25,0 3.54,-1.93 3.54,0 1.77,3.08 0.59,3.86 -2.65,7.7 -1.66,2.47 0,0 -5.13,8.7 0,4.71 0,0 -4.16,-0.65 -4.47,-2.78 -19.84,-7.51 -5.75,-7.24 -1.5,-0.84 -1.49,0.56 -7.25,8.63 -3.2,1.67 -2.98,0 -3.84,-1.67 -1.92,-3.9 -2.13,-1.39 -2.35,0.83 1.28,20.04 -2.99,2.22 -22.39,-0.55 -7.46,-2.23 -15.78,-2.78 -10.45,-3.34 -9.81,-0.83 -10.88,-8.91 -3.199995,-0.83 -0.64,-4.73 -2.77,-0.84 -6.61,0 -4.69,-0.83 -7.68,-3.62 -14.29,1.11 -5.54,3.34 -1.4,1.69 0,0 -8.02,-3.59 -0.33,-5.11 -1.65,-5.47 -10.58,-10.81 -0.95,-1.86 0.83,-3.42 7.97,-13.31 -0.54,-6.12 -1.54,-3.52 -1.03,-1.65 -2.89,-2.11 0,0 4.68,-0.51 9.86,-2.58 8.22,-6.89 2.31,-4.31 6.25,-4.3 9.53,-0.87 3.29,-0.86 3.29,-2.15 2.63,-0.43 3.62,2.58 5.59,1.73 5.589995,-0.44 2.3,-1.72 2.96,0 4.28,1.72 3.94,3.02 6.91,0 7.56,-4.31 4.28,0 4.6,1.29 5.92,6.04 4.6,0.43 2.63,-1.73 2.96,-0.86 5.27,0 3.61,1.29 4.61,0 10.19,-3.87 3.62,-3.45 2.96,0 1.32,-3.45 0,-3.44 -5.6,-6.47 -0.32,-3.88 0,-5.61 2.96,-7.76 -11.84,-1.72 0,-6.91 -0.99,-3.02 -7.56,-11.66 -0.33,-4.75 0.98,-4.75 3.29,-3.89 4.94,-3.89 5.26,-1.3 7.56,-0.43 z" title="Aragac̣otn" id="AM-AG" fill="red" />
  <text x="150" y="310" font-size="20">Лорем</text>

  <path d="m 233.3325,425.38394 -1.43,-2.65 -2.73,-2.78 -6.58,-1.84 -3.04,-1.96 0,0 1.99,-15.36 -0.21,-3.33 -5.97,-7.78 -0.64,-3.61 0.85,-3.33 2.34,-1.39 5.76,-0.56 10.88,0.28 5.54,0.83 2.14,1.95 2.13,0.55 0.39,-0.81 0,0 6.6,6.55 3.84,1.54 5.01,0.38 3.84,1.92 4.72,4.99 1.77,0.77 1.48,-0.77 5.01,-5.76 5.02,-0.38 2.65,-1.15 4.72,-4.62 5.91,-3.84 5.16,-8.27 0,0 -0.59,13.84 3.24,5 6.5,1.92 5.01,-0.38 2.07,-0.77 0,-3.85 1.47,-1.53 3.54,0 2.66,-3.08 2.65,-0.77 3.54,0.39 1.19,-3.85 2.06,-3.07 17.56,-0.96 4.13,-9.23 4.42,-1.93 4.72,0.39 5.32,-2.31 23.89,0.77 1.14,-0.89 0,0 1.37,0.7 0,1.92 -3.54,19.23 0,9.99 20.95,31.86 -0.29,14.96 1.47,4.22 0,6.89 -1.47,12.65 1.98,3.54 0,0 0.38,0.67 -7.97,5.36 -3.25,5.35 -1.47,4.6 -0.79,7.14 0,0 -1.91,0 -6.17,4.31 -2.85,3.69 -2.17,5.84 -5.67,3.53 -5.72,2.31 -3.77,0.9 -14.59,0.26 -14.91,1.63 -8.52,1.16 -7.06,2.23 -2.46,-0.34 -1.26,-1.33 0.42,-4.97 -2.37,-1.38 -3.44,0.15 -1.31,-5.07 -3.3,-4.51 -1.42,-0.9 -2.8,0.94 0.16,-2.6 1.55,-4 -2.32,-1.81 -1.7,0.05 -1.95,1.59 -2.08,0.24 -13.39,-8.94 1.32,-2.37 -0.34,-1.8 -4.38,1.52 -1.59,-0.61 -0.75,-1.08 -0.41,-7 -1.68,-2.99 -4.12,-2.91 -2.36,-2.81 -1.66,-8.55 -4.24,-4.85 -4.37,-2.48 -8.56,-12.52 -5.76,-1.67 -2.58,-2.89 -8.99,-6.77 -5.47,0 z" title="Ararat" id="AM-AR" fill="green" />

  <text x="300" y="450" font-size="20px">Лорем2</text>
</svg>
```